# Multi levels of question-answer tree Angular 6 reactive forms

Tags: angular

I have to implement a nested tree structure based on some question and answer hierarchy. The first question is the root element and then by clicking on a button multiple answers could be added to that question. And if the answer is written for one of this, then corresponding question and answer pair will be added as a child element of that answer. Then again the same steps could be applied recursively. E.g.,

```
'question': '',
        'answer': [
            {
                'question': '',
                'answer': [
                    {
                        'question': '',
                        'answer': [
                            {
                                'question': '',
                                'answer': [
                                    {
                                        'question': '',
                                        'answer': []
                                    },
                                    {
                                        'question': '',
                                        'answer': [
                                            {
                                                'question': '',
                                                'answer': [
                                                    {
                                                        'question': '',
                                                        'answer': [
                                                            {
                                                                'question': '',
                                                                'answer': [
                                                                    {
                                                                        'question': '',
                                                                        'answer': []
                                                                    },
                                                                ]
                                                            },
                                                        ]
                                                    },
                                                    {
                                                        'question': '',
                                                        'answer': []
                                                    },
                                                ]
                                            },
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    {
                                        'question': '',
                                        'answer': []
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                'question': '',
                                'answer': []
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                'question': '',
                'answer': []
            },
            {
                'question': '',
                'answer': []
            }
        ]
```

- component.ts file

```js
import { Question } from './question';
import { Answer } from './answer';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import {
  Form, FormGroup, FormBuilder,
  FormArray, Validators, FormControl
} from '@angular/forms';
import { Component, OnInit, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-analysis-form',
  // encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  templateUrl: './analysis-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./analysis-form.component.css']
})
export class AnalysisFormComponent implements OnInit {

  questionAnswerForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.initForm();
  }

  initForm(): void {

    const questions: FormArray = new FormArray([]);
    const answers: FormArray = new FormArray([]);

    this.questionAnswerForm = new FormGroup({
      // question_title: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      questions: questions,
      answers: answers
    });

    this.addQuestion();
    this.addAnswer(0);

  }

  get answerIndexes() {
    return this.questionAnswerForm.get('questions') as FormArray;
  }

  addQuestion(question?: Question): void {
    const answers = new FormArray([]);
    const question_title = question ? question.question_title : '';
    (<FormArray>this.questionAnswerForm.controls['questions']).push(
      new FormGroup({
        question_title: new FormControl(question_title, Validators.required),
        answers: answers
      })
    );
  }

  addQtoAns(qIndex: number, answerIndex: number, question?: Question): void {
    console.log(qIndex);
    console.log(answerIndex);
    const answers = new FormArray([]);
    const question_title = question ? question.question_title : '';

    // console.log(this.questionAnswerForm.controls['questions'].value);

    // console.log(this.questionAnswerForm.controls['answers'].at())

    (<FormArray>(<FormGroup>(<FormArray>this.questionAnswerForm.controls['questions'])
      .controls[answerIndex]).controls['answers']).push(
        new FormGroup({
          question_title: new FormControl(question_title, Validators.required),
          answers: answers
        })
      );



    // .push(
    //   new FormGroup({
    //     question_title: new FormControl(question_title, Validators.required),
    //     answers: answers
    //   })
    // );

    // (
    //   <FormArray>
    //   (
    //     <FormGroup>
    //     (<FormArray>this.questionAnswerForm.controls['questions'])
    //       .controls[qIndex]
    //   )
    //     .controls['answers']
    // )
    //   .push(
    //     new FormGroup({
    //       question_title: new FormControl(question_title, Validators.required),
    //       answers: answers
    //     })
    //   );
  }

  addAnswer(answerIndex: number, answer?: Answer): void {
    const answer_title = answer ? answer.answer_title : '';

    (<FormArray>(<FormGroup>(<FormArray>this.questionAnswerForm.controls['questions'])
      .controls[answerIndex]).controls['answers']).push(
        new FormGroup({
          answer_title: new FormControl(answer_title, Validators.required),
        })
      );
  }

  deleteAnswer(index) {
    console.log(index);

    (<FormArray>(<FormGroup>(<FormArray>this.questionAnswerForm.controls['questions'])
      .controls[index]).controls['answers']).removeAt(index);

    // (<FormArray>(<FormArray>this.questionAnswerForm.controls['questions']).controls['answers']).removeAt(index);
  }

  // deleteAnswer(answerIndex: number): void {
  //   (<FormArray>(<FormGroup>(<FormArray>this.questionAnswerForm.controls['questions'])
  //     .controls[answerIndex]).controls['answers']).removeAt(answerIndex);
  // }

}
```

And that is my html file

```js
<div class="ui two column grid" style="margin-top:20px;">
  <div class="column create-form">

    <form class="ui form" [formGroup]="questionAnswerForm">
      <div class="main-container">
        <div class="list-group" formArrayName="questions">
          <div *ngFor="let question of questionAnswerForm.controls['questions'].controls; let i = index">
            <div class="question-box" formGroupName="{{i}}">
              <div class="fields">
                <div class="field eight wide">
                  <label for="description">Question: </label>
                  <input type="text" placeholder="question" formControlName="question_title" size="70">
                </div>
              </div>
              <!-- Places basic info -->
              <!--TODO: Add provision for places later-->
              <div class="container">
                <!-- <h2 class="side"> Answers </h2> -->
                <!-- <button type="button" class="circular ui icon button" (click)="addAnswer(i)"> -->
                <mat-icon (click)="addAnswer(i)">add_circle_outline</mat-icon>
                <!-- </button> -->
                <label for="description">Answer: </label>
                <div class="row" formArrayName="answers">
                  <div class="col-sm" *ngFor="let answer of question.controls['answers'].controls; let j = index"
                    [formGroupName]="j">

                    <input type="text" placeholder="answer" formControlName="answer_title">

                    <mat-icon (click)="deleteAnswer(i)">delete</mat-icon>

                    <mat-icon (click)="addQtoAns(i, j)">add_circle_outline</mat-icon>
                    <!-- <button type="button" (click)="deleteAnswer(j)">Delete</button> -->
                    <!-- <div class="answer-box" formGroupName="{{j}}">
                      <div class="fields">
                        <div class="field eight wide">
                          <label for="description">Answer: </label>
                          <input type="text" size="70" placeholder="Because it does not come up to support the part against forces from the machining process."
                            formControlName="name">
                          <button type="button" (click)="deleteAnswer(j)">Delete</button>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div> -->
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="vertical-line"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="add-question-wrapper">
            <div class="ui primary animated button add-question-button" tabindex="0" (click)="addQuestion()">
              <div class="visible content">Add Question</div>
              <div class="hidden content">
                <mat-icon>add_circle_outline</mat-icon>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <button class="ui secondary basic button" (click)="onCancel()">Cancel</button>
          <button type="submit" *ngIf="!isEditing" class="ui primary basic button" [disabled]="!tripForm.valid">Save</button>
          <button type="submit" *ngIf="isEditing" class="ui primary basic button" [disabled]="!tripForm.valid">Update</button>
        </div>
      </div> -->
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="column result">
    <h1>Form Validity and Values</h1>
    <h3>Form Validity: {{questionAnswerForm.valid}}</h3>
    <h3>Form Value: {{questionAnswerForm.value | json}}</h3>

  </div>
</div>

<br />
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-between">
  <button mat-raised-button style="background:#b3b3b3" matStepperPrevious>Prev</button>
  <button mat-raised-button style="background:#b3b3b3" matStepperNext>Next</button>
</div>
```

I am struggling with this for the last couple of days. However, could not get out of this riddle.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Is json structure is fixed or any possibility to change the JSON structure of your question answer object?

Comment: It's not fixed. However, the level could be extended for at most 5 steps.

Comment: I understand this is dynamic form, but my point is related to your JSON structure, is there any chances to restructure your json for simplification because current json structure is little bit complex. Please reply so that I can guide you accordingly

Comment: Thanks @AjayOjha for your quick reply. Yes, JSON structure might be compromised for the sake of the solution. However, the idea still need to be the same. That is, "Why late?" -> (1) { "The bus was late" -> "What happened to the bus?" -> "One wheel need to be changed" } -> (2) {"What did you eat at breakfast?" -> "Pasta" -> "What type of Pasta?" -> ...}. Just an example for your convenience. Thanks again.

Comment: Ok thanks for this update will update you in couple of hours, I have one more question to you, in this dynamic form is there any dynamic validations required, if yes then please share some info on that

Comment: no, validations is not required. However, I need the 'delete' functionality over there to remove the 'Q-A' pair if one wants to. Eagerly waiting for your reply. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have one more question, Sorry for the asking more question. today, I was busy in some other activity, now I am creating a sample application for you, while creating I have a two questions: like say for example when the user opens a screen at that time the question will come : "Why Late?" then user will enter the text or select the predefined values from the dropdown? and second question is once user will select or enters the value then all other children question we have to show? or something different.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184926/discussion-between-yasir-arefin-and-ajay-ojha).

Comment: Please refer stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/n-level-question-answer-reactive-form-dynamic?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts for tree structure reactive form. Please let me know if you have any question. I have created questionId and parentQuestionId for identification of child questions. When you click on save button, you will get complete form data. please let me know if you have any question. I haven't focus on UI part.

Comment: I know, only thanks would not be enough for your effort @AjayOjha. Nonetheless, thanks a lot. However, right now I am working on this. I will let you if anything would come up...

Comment: Sure, I have written all code in one file, if it's confusing then please message me anytime.